# Getting issue when trying to insert elements in middle of XML file while parsing through ElementTree module using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I am parsing xml files by reading the files from source path and writing in target path after modifying the selected tags. I have written this logic using Element Tree module in python3. Until now everything is working fine.

What I need now is,
which I have no idea how to add sub elements in the middle of xml file while parsing by reading from source path and writing in target path. Below provided are the details

### Input file & python logic:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mapper VERSION="1.0" xmlns="http://www.stercomm.com/SI/Map" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MapDetails>
<Summary>
<Author>ishak</Author>
<Description>CV_ORA_DCBR_I_001_03_SPE</Description>
<MapFunction>24</MapFunction>
</Summary>
<ExplicitRule>
<PreSessionRule>Integer last_date,PE3_DUMMY,cnt_PE,cnt_DTL ,cnt_4000,cnt_PE3_grp,PE5_DUMMY;

String[80] CURR_DATE,FileName,LookUP,Var_plant_code,Var_partner_name;
String[256] Var_EDI_LOC,Var_EDI_LOC_1,FLAG_C;
Var_EDI_LOC_1 ="";
PE3_DUMMY =0;
</PreSessionRule>
</ExplicitRule>
</MapDetails>
<Name>PE5</Name>
<Description>SHIP./DELIV. COMPLEMENT SCHEDULE</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>22</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Min>0</Min>
<Max>99999</Max>
<LoopCtl>normal</LoopCtl>
<OrderingType>0</OrderingType>
<OrderingTag></OrderingTag>
<UsageRelatedFieldName/><BlockSig>
<Tag>PE5</Tag>
<TagPos>0</TagPos>
<KeyFieldID>0</KeyFieldID>
<KeyFieldData>0</KeyFieldData>
<KeyFieldAction>65535</KeyFieldAction>
<Tag></Tag>
<TagPos>0</TagPos>
<KeyFieldID>0</KeyFieldID>
<KeyFieldData>0</KeyFieldData>
<KeyFieldAction>0</KeyFieldAction>
</BlockSig>
<TagLength>0</TagLength>
<Field>
<ID>534</ID>
<Name>START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>6</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>3</StartPos>
<Length>6</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>533</ID>
<Name>PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>1</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>9</StartPos>
<Length>1</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>532</ID>
<Name>ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>9</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<ExplicitRule></ExplicitRule>
<StartPos>10</StartPos>
<Length>9</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>531</ID>
<Name>START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:2</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>6</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>19</StartPos>
<Length>6</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>530</ID>
<Name>PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION:2</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>1</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>25</StartPos>
<Length>1</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>529</ID>
<Name>ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM:2</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>9</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<ExplicitRule></ExplicitRule>
<StartPos>26</StartPos>
<Length>9</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>528</ID>
<Name>START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:3</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>6</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>35</StartPos>
<Length>6</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>527</ID>
<Name>PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION:3</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>1</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>41</StartPos>
<Length>1</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>526</ID>
<Name>ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM:3</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>9</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<ExplicitRule></ExplicitRule>
<StartPos>42</StartPos>
<Length>9</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>525</ID>
<Name>START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:4</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>6</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>51</StartPos>
<Length>6</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>524</ID>
<Name>PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION:4</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>1</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>57</StartPos>
<Length>1</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>523</ID>
<Name>ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM:4</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>9</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<ExplicitRule></ExplicitRule>
<StartPos>58</StartPos>
<Length>9</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>522</ID>
<Name>START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:5</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>6</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>67</StartPos>
<Length>6</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>521</ID>
<Name>PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION:5</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>1</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>73</StartPos>
<Length>1</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>520</ID>
<Name>ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM:5</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>9</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<ExplicitRule></ExplicitRule>
<StartPos>74</StartPos>
<Length>9</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>519</ID>
<Name>START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:6</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>6</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>83</StartPos>
<Length>6</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>518</ID>
<Name>PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION:6</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>1</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>89</StartPos>
<Length>1</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>517</ID>
<Name>ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM:6</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>9</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<ExplicitRule>if #START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:6!="000000" then
Begin
PE5_DUMMY=PE5_DUMMY+1;
$TEMP_PE5[1][cnt_PE][cnt_PE3_grp][PE5_DUMMY].#START_DATE=#START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:6;
$TEMP_PE5[1][cnt_PE][cnt_PE3_grp][PE5_DUMMY].#PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION_1=#PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION:6;
$TEMP_PE5[1][cnt_PE][cnt_PE3_grp][PE5_DUMMY].#PRGM_ID=#ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM:6;
End</ExplicitRule>
<StartPos>90</StartPos>
<Length>9</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>516</ID>
<Name>START_DELIVERY_DATE_SHIPMENT_ITEM:7</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>6</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>99</StartPos>
<Length>6</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>515</ID>
<Name>PROGRAMMING_IDENTIFICATION:7</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>1</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>105</StartPos>
<Length>1</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>514</ID>
<Name>ID_CURRENT_PROGRAM:7</Name>
<Description>INITIAL DATE TO ITEM SHIP/DELIVERY</Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>9</MaxLen>
<MinLen>0</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<ExplicitRule></ExplicitRule>
<StartPos>106</StartPos>
<Length>9</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
<Field>
<ID>513</ID>
<Name>BLANK:3</Name>
<Description></Description>
<Active>1</Active>
<ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
<Note></Note>
<Mandatory>no</Mandatory>
<NotUsed>no</NotUsed>
<FieldNumber>0</FieldNumber>
<StoreGroup>65535</StoreGroup>
<StoreField>65535</StoreField>
<BusinessName></BusinessName>
<StoreLimit>
<MaxLen>13</MaxLen>
<MinLen>1</MinLen>
<Signed>no</Signed>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<ImpliedDecimalPos>0</ImpliedDecimalPos>
<ImplicitDecimal>no</ImplicitDecimal>
<AllowSignedDecimal>1</AllowSignedDecimal>
<Format></Format>
<BinaryOutput>0</BinaryOutput>
<BinaryWidth>0</BinaryWidth>
</StoreLimit>
<StartPos>115</StartPos>
<Length>13</Length>
<Justify>left</Justify>
<PadChar>SP</PadChar>
<PadHighByte>0</PadHighByte>
<Binary>0</Binary>
</Field>
</PosRecord>
<SyntaxTokens>
<Token>
<Code>A</Code>
<Range>
<Start>Z</Start>
<End>A</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>z</Start>
<End>a</End>
</Range>
<Char>SP</Char>
<Char>SP</Char>
</Token>
<Token>
<Code>N</Code>
<Range>
<Start>9</Start>
<End>0</End>
</Range>
<Char>.</Char>
<Char>-</Char>
<Char>+</Char>
</Token>
<Token>
<Code>X</Code>
<Range>
<Start>Z</Start>
<End>A</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>z</Start>
<End>a</End>
</Range>
<Char>.</Char>
<Char>-</Char>
<Char>+</Char>
<Char>SP</Char>
<Char>(</Char>
<Char>)</Char>
<Char>:</Char>
<Char>/</Char>
<Char>%</Char>
<Char>\</Char>
<Char>!</Char>
<Char>"</Char>
<Char>$</Char>
<Char>^</Char>
<Char>&amp;</Char>
<Char>*</Char>
<Char>_</Char>
<Char>=</Char>
<Char>[</Char>
<Char>]</Char>
<Char>{</Char>
<Char>}</Char>
<Char>;</Char>
<Char>'</Char>
<Char>?</Char>
<Char>,</Char>
<Char>&lt;</Char>
<Char>&gt;</Char>
<Char>~</Char>
<Char>#</Char>
<Char>|</Char>
<Char>@</Char>
<Char>`</Char>
</Token>
<Token>
<Code>J</Code>
<Range>
<Start>Z</Start>
<End>A</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>z</Start>
<End>a</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>9</Start>
<End>0</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>/</Start>
<End>!</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>@</Start>
<End>:</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>`</Start>
<End>[</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>~</Start>
<End>{</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>0xDF</Start>
<End>0xA1</End>
</Range>
<Char>SP</Char>
</Token>
</SyntaxTokens>
<ConstantMap xml:space="preserve">
<Constant>
<ConstantID>tp_code</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>abc123</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>CT</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>CT</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>CTL</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>CTL</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>ED</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>ED</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>T</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>T</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>SPSI</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>SPSI</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>STAND</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>STAND</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>OR</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>OR</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>HD</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>HD</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>HDR</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>HDR</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>SFH</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>SFH</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>Search Key 1</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>TranslationOutput/BusinessReference</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>SC</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>SC</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>SCH</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>SCH</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>A1</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>A1</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>SD1</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>SD1</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>Search Key 2</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>TranslationOutput/BusinessReference</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>AD</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>AD</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>SFI</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>SFI</Value>
</Constant>
<Constant>
<ConstantID>RF</ConstantID>
<Type>String</Type>
<Value>RF</Value>
</Constant></ConstantMap></Mapper>




Below is the data I need to modify in above input file after parsing through python3 :
------------------------------------------------------------------

before parsing (current the data is present like):
--------------------------------------------------
<Token>
<Code>X</Code>
<Range>
<Start>Z</Start>
<End>A</End>
</Range>

after parsing I need data inside Token element is like :
--------------------------------------------------------
<Token>
<Code>X</Code>
<Range>
<Start>0xFF</Start>
<End>0x01</End>
</Range>
<Range>
<Start>Z</Start>
<End>A</End>
</Range>

This is the logic I am using:
-----------------------------
import os, os.path
import shutil, glob, re
from datetime import date
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

source_path = "C:\\Users\\"+os.getlogin()+"\\Documents\\test\\source"
target_path = "C:\\Users\\"+os.getlogin()+"\\Documents\\test\\target"
source0 =     "C:\\Users\\"+os.getlogin()+"\\Documents\\test"

today = date.today()
current_date = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")                                          #Current date

var_username = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', os.getlogin())                           #getting username

path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(source_path))                                       #read all files from source dir


for filename in files:
    fullname = os.path.join(source_path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)                                                                                          # XML Parsing
    root = tree.getroot()

    ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.stercomm.com/SI/Map")                                                             #removing namespaces-ns0
    Desc_Flag = "N"                                                                                             #To modify only 1st occurence of Description tag


    for elem in tree.iter():         

        if elem.tag == "{http://www.stercomm.com/SI/Map}Author":
            elem.text = 'IYM'
            #print(elem.tag,elem.text)        
        if elem.tag == "{http://www.stercomm.com/SI/Map}Description" and Desc_Flag == "N":
            elem.text = filename
            Desc_Flag = "Y"             
        if elem.tag == "{http://www.stercomm.com/SI/Map}CharacterEncoding":
            elem.text = 'Cp1252 (Cp1252)'             
        if elem.tag == "{http://www.stercomm.com/SI/Map}PreSessionRule":   
            elem.text = "Created on: "+current_date+"     "+"BY: "+var_username[1]+"\r\n"+elem.text  




    tree.write(filename, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True, method="xml")   # To write to a file

    for mxl_file in glob.iglob('*.mxl'):                                                                                     #files moving to target location
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source0, mxl_file), os.path.join(target_path, mxl_file))

#print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml').decode('utf8'))                                                 #Printing on cmd prompt after parsing```
````